# Understanding Memory/process Requirements in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, database-performance

I have an active rails application with `3 sidekiq workers` for **async** jobs.Now i know that Ruby allocates memory in two heaps. All Ruby objects go to Ruby's own heap. **Each object has 40 bytes** (on a 64-bit system) to store its data.When object needs to store more, it will allocate space in operating system's heap.Now with this in mind,**Can i calculate how much RAM do i need** to stop **OOM**(*out of memory error*) OR **how can i understand that a default of number of concurrent users my rails application can handle** without going in OOM.How can i calculate it..such as `3 sidekiq + one Rails app = something MB`..SO I can understand that how much memory i needs to server more users such as 1000+ concurrent users. **can i benchmark my application and how it can help me**

Comment: This depends on so many factors we don't know it's difficult to even guess in any meaningful way. How could we possibly know the memory requirements of your application? How about you just profile it?

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton..Thanks.but still there can be a way i can count the RAM ..or atleast how much users can i handle by default...or something like this....?